# How does Android NFC realize multiple card reading by sticking a card once?

Tags: android

An application developed by Android. Some of its functions are to read the information in the NFC card. It is isodep type. It can be realized by reading the information in the NFC card at a single time, but it cannot be recognized if you want to read it again. You need to remove the card and fit it again, or turn off the screen and unlock the bright screen before reading it again. So is there any good way to fit the card only once, and then read the information in the NFC card many times? thank you!

Comment: Are you using kt or java?

Comment: Let me get this straight, are you trying to read the same card multiple times or different cards multiple times? Cause I'm sure you can read multiple cards without having to lock your phone, could you elaborate pls?

Comment: @TomasMota java

Comment: @TomasMota  to read the same card multiple times.

Comment: Alright. If you don't mind me asking, why would you want to do that? The NDEF message doesn't change so you will just be reading the same message over and over. Could you elaborate please, so I can furtherly help you?

Comment: @TomasMota   to read the same card multiple times.Such as reading version information and id in different click event . Now,my problem is that after I first read the version information by clicking the event, the code in the onNewIntent function will be executed. If I want to get the ID of the card through another click event, it will not execute the code in the onNewIntent function, that is, it will not trigger the execution of the onnewintent function. If I turn off the screen and then turn on the screen, it will take effect and achieve the desired effect.

Comment: @TomasMota `@Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
        IsoDep isodep = IsoDep.get(tag);
        try {
            isodep.connect();
            processData(isodep);
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }finally {
            try{
                isodep.close();
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }`